# cannot find how 'F1' key works in application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

My application is built in MFC.After the application executes I need to open the help file provided with exe.

But as I press F1 application gives an error message saying the file cannot be found. This happens because no such file of that name exist.

One would think how about changing the name of help file itself? well that cannot be done I have to change the path as well.

I need to know how does the function of F1 button work and where can I find the same?

I am using VC++ 6.0 (I know its very old, but I am stuck with it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To show your specific help file, you have to overwrite `CWinApp::OnHelp`. The path to the standard help file is stored in `CWinApp::m_pszHelpFilePath`. In this example, I use my own `m_path` variable.

```
void CMyApp::OnHelp() 
{
    ::HtmlHelp(((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_hWnd,m_path,HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, by default it's handled by `CWinApp::OnHelp()` so take a look at your override of the application class first, you may find the `ON_COMMAND` handler there.

Answer (score 1):

I had an class that extends `CWinApp`, so overwriting the `OnHelp` function worked this way:

In the header:

```
class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    afx_msg void OnHelp();
}
```

In the cpp file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, MyApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MyApp::OnHelp()
{
    // your own help function
}
```